# Django Rest Framework to return dicts instead of OrderedDicts

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer with two attached `SerializerMethodField` fields:

```
class BentoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    zones = SerializerMethodField()
    lead_zone = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_zones(self, obj):
        zone_queryset = obj.get_zones()
        return ZoneSerializer(zone_queryset, many=True).data

    def get_lead_zone(self, obj):
        zone_queryset = obj.get_lead_zone()
        return ZoneSerializer(zone_queryset).data

    class Meta:
        model = Bento
        fields = ('lead_zone', 'zones', )
```

I need the data coming out of the serializer to be nested JSON (the ZoneSerializer contains similar `SerializerMethodField`s of its own, alongside normal model fields) but instead it comes out as an OrderedDict.

Is there a way to configure the serializer such that `BentoSerializer(obj).data` return nested JSON, should I be recursively turning the OrderedDicts into dicts, or is there some other serializer method I don't know about for getting non-ordered data?

Many thanks!

PS: Example data currently coming from a factory object sent through the serializer:

```
[OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('columns', [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('blocks', [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('block_type', 'Text'), ('blockcontent', 'Cum inventore sed fugit aliquam doloribus. Alias exercitationem odit asperiores rerum qui aperiam cum fugit.'), ('heading', 'Adipisci possimus dolore assumenda sapiente velit amet odio doloremque.')])]), ('sticky', False), ('weight', 12), ('is_slideshow', False)])]), ('has_background_image', False), ('is_lead', False), ('is_slideshow', False), ('background_image', None), ('background_treatment', 'dark')])]
<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList'>
{'lead_zone': {'background_image': None,
               'background_treatment': 'dark',
               'columns': [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('blocks', [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('block_type', 'Image'), ('blockcontent', '/media/media/2018/06/22/adatestfile_SfZMYPw.png'), ('heading', 'Reprehenderit officiis aliquid inventore enim quibusdam inventore beatae.')])]), ('sticky', False), ('weight', 12), ('is_slideshow', False)])],
               'has_background_image': False,
               'is_lead': True,
               'is_slideshow': False,
               'order': 1},
 'zones': [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('columns', [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('blocks', [OrderedDict([('order', 1), ('block_type', 'Text'), ('blockcontent', 'Cum inventore sed fugit aliquam doloribus. Alias exercitationem odit asperiores rerum qui aperiam cum fugit.'), ('heading', 'Adipisci possimus dolore assumenda sapiente velit amet odio doloremque.')])]), ('sticky', False), ('weight', 12), ('is_slideshow', False)])]), ('has_background_image', False), ('is_lead', False), ('is_slideshow', False), ('background_image', None), ('background_treatment', 'dark')])]}
```

Comment: your headline and question contradicts!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

class/models are serialized into an OrderedDict type to be consumed by the `Response` method through this import `from rest_framework.response import Response` in combination with Django Rest Framework Views. It will typically return the data in a content-type that is either assigned at runtime through the `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` project setting, assigned through a serializer property that is passed on initialization, or will be determined by the `Accept` header sent during the request. Details can be found in the DRF documentation at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/.

Thus, calling `Response(BentoSerializer(obj).data)` should return JSON formatted data to the client when passed through a view such as APIView, or a route on a ModelViewSet.

However, you can also just `import json` and call `json.dumps(BentoSerializer(obj).data)` and the desired JSON will be output. I tested this with my own serializers in the django shell.

## EDIT

Note that you cannot simply dump a datetime... You will likely end up having to write a patch to convert datetime and date objects to the format you expect.

eg.

```
def json_dt_patch(o):
    import datetime
    from decimal import Decimal

    if isinstance(o, datetime.date) or isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    elif isinstance(o, Decimal):
        return str(o)
    return o

import json

json.dumps(data, default=json_dt_patch)
```

Comment: Thank you both for a clearer understanding of how the serializer fits into the DRF workflow, and the tip for just dumping the JSON!

Comment: `json.dumps(data['attributes'])` doesn't work for me.  I get the error 'Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable'.  I believe this is referring to the list that contains each attribute.

Comment: attributes is a related queryset field. You would need to first serialize it. eg. `json.dumps(AttributeSerializer(data["attributes"], many=True).data)`

Answer (score 2):

While getting Ordered Dict from serializer validator you can convert it easily to the full form of Dict like JSONRenderer. This is usually returned in nested serializers.

```
    serializer = XXXSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    payload = loads(dumps(serializer.data))
    print(payload)
```

From

```
{'connection_alias': 'dev', 'payment_gateway_type': 'Stripe', 'restaurant_id': 'STRIPE_SANDBOX_TEST', 'card_info': OrderedDict([('card_type', 'VISA'), ('card_number', 'xxxxx'), ('card_expiry_month', 'xx'), ('card_expiry_year', 'xx'), ('card_cvc', 'xxx'), ('cardholder_name', 'xxxxxx')])
```

To

```
{'connection_alias': 'dev', 'payment_gateway_type': 'Stripe', 'restaurant_id': 'STRIPE_SANDBOX_TEST', 'card_info': {'card_type': 'VISA', 'card_number': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'card_expiry_month': 'xx', 'card_expiry_year': 'xx', 'card_cvc': 'xxx', 'cardholder_name': 'xxxxxx'}}
```

Comment: combine this with default=json_dt_patch from Nicolas's answer if the object included decimals or datetimes

Answer (score 1):

This is addendum to @NicholasClaudeLeBlanc's answer.

I couldn't get `json.dumps` to work in my context.  The actual JSON renderer used by django-rest-framework can be obtained like this:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
renderer = JSONRenderer()
renderer.render
```

[renderer's documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
class BentoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    zones = SerializerMethodField()
    lead_zone = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_zones(self, obj):
        zone_data = ZoneSerializer(obj.zones, many=True)
        data_list = []
        for i in zone_data.data:
            data_list.append(dict(i))
        return data_list

    def get_lead_zone(self, obj):

        lead_zone_data = ZoneSerializer(obj.lead_zone, many=True)
        data_list = []
        for i in lead_zone_data.data:
            data_list.append(dict(i))
        return data_list

    class Meta:
        model = Bento
        fields = ('lead_zone', 'zones', )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself on this question.  I was looking to write a test case that `assertDictEqual`.  My mistake was looking at `response.data` instead of `response.json()`.  `response.data` contained the OrderedDict since it hadn't been rendered yet.